# XML to Excel column width is not staying fixed

Tags: excel, xslt

I am converting xml to Excel via XSLT 1.0. I have assigned the columns and rows a fixed value and removed the auto adjustment of width/height.

```
<Column ss:StyleID="s180" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="112.5"/>
...
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="15" ss:StyleID="s67">
```

However this doesn't seem to actually be happening. I have varying reports from users that conflict with my own machine. Of course the mysterious conversion factor from XSLT's ss:width and Excel's width applies.

```
    Column:
         User 1 - 38.09
         User 2 - 20.82
         My Machine - 20.74
    Row:
         User 1 - 14.50
         User 2 - 15.15
         My Machine - 15.00
```

I've searched as many query strings as I can think of trying to understand why the set value I have isn't being adhered to. I've even checked the page setup, but I'm not fitting to the page and the scale is a set value as well.

```
<FitToPage/>
<Print>
        <ValidPrinterInfo/>
        <Scale>71</Scale>
        <HorizontalResolution>600</HorizontalResolution>
        <VerticalResolution>600</VerticalResolution>
</Print>
```

As far as I read this the Excel document should always maintain the same width/height, but that isn't being seen when deployed.

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this forum message](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/386925-excel-column-width-units.html)

> You are correct, column width measurement is an odd-ball in Excel. 1
>   increment of column width is equal to the width of the zero character of the
>   font used by the Normal style for a workbook. So a column of width 10 would
>   fit exactly 10 zero characters in the font specified by the Normal style.

So it appears you don't have complete control over what column width units mean.

Comment: Understood, but given I have declared the StyleID that lets me basically assign a width based on that style doesn't it? I read the code as saying "set column = x and font = y". Since I set font/style shouldn't I remove any chance of flexibility in the column width?